# Sort lines within file based on folder in path

Tags: sorting, powershell, scripting, filesystems

I have a file with below lines

```
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\scripts\scripts1.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\tables\scripts1.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\storedprocedures\scripts1.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\functions\scripts1.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\tables\scripts2.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\storedprocedures\scripts2.sql
```

I am looking for a powershell script that can sort based on list as mentioned below...

```
Tables,storedprocedures,views,scripts,everything else.....
```

My expected output is

```
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\tables\scripts1.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\tables\scripts2.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\storedprocedures\scripts1.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\storedprocedures\scripts2.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\scripts\scripts1.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\functions\scripts1.sql
```

Comment: Did you try to write it yourself? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Sort-Object -Property` can take anonymous calculated properties as its argument. Put a switch inside the expression based on your sorting criteria:

```
function Test-CustomSort {
    $ScriptNames  = @(
        'c:\scripts\oltp\db1\scripts\scripts1.sql'
        'c:\scripts\oltp\db1\tables\scripts1.sql'
        'c:\scripts\oltp\db1\storedprocedures\scripts1.sql'
        'c:\scripts\oltp\db1\functions\scripts1.sql'
        'c:\scripts\oltp\db1\tables\scripts2.sql'
        'c:\scripts\oltp\db1\storedprocedures\scripts2.sql'
    )

    $ScriptNames | Sort-Object @{Expression={
        switch(Split-Path -Parent $_ | Split-Path -Leaf){
            "tables"           { 1 }
            "storedprocedures" { 2 }
            "views"            { 3 }
            "scripts"          { 4 }
            default            { 5 }
        }
    }}
}
```

Produces:

```
PS C:\> Test-CustomSort
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\tables\scripts1.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\tables\scripts2.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\storedprocedures\scripts1.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\storedprocedures\scripts2.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\scripts\scripts1.sql
c:\scripts\oltp\db1\functions\scripts1.sql
```

Answer (score 2):

You could group the paths by directory, put them into a hashtable, then output the hashtable in the desired order.

```
$categories = 'tables', 'storedprocedures', 'views', 'scripts', 'functions'

$ht = @{}
Get-Content 'C:\path\to\your.txt' |
  Group-Object { Split-Path -Parent $_ | Split-Path -Leaf } |
  ForEach-Object { $ht[$_.Name] = $_.Group }

$categories | ForEach-Object {
  $ht[$_] | Sort-Object
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the path is always the same : c:\scripts\oltp\db1\

```
(gc .\list.txt) | %{$_ -replace 'c:\\scripts\\oltp\\db1\\', ''} | Sort
```

Output

```
functions\scripts1.sql
scripts\scripts1.sql
storedprocedures\scripts1.sql
storedprocedures\scripts2.sql
tables\scripts1.sql
tables\scripts2.sql
```

Comment: The OP does not want alphabetical order.